# GetPrivateProfileString: Strange Behaviour, works only when the file is excluded and included again in project

Tags: vb.net, winapi, ini

I am working on a migration project from VB6 to VB.NET 4.0 (VS 2013 Professional) where I am supposed to use INI file for reading inputs (client requirements).

To read a specific file path, code calls the function to read INI file. The declaration is as:

```
Dim i As Integer = IniFile.GetPrivateProfileString(Section, Key, "", temp, 1024, m_sIniFileName)


 <DllImport("kernel32")> _
Public Shared Function GetPrivateProfileString(ByVal section As String, ByVal key As String, ByVal def As String, ByVal retVal As System.Text.StringBuilder, ByVal size As Integer, ByVal filePath As String) As Integer
End Function
```

where m_sIniFileName is of type String.

The strange thing is, when I freshly open the solution, no value is returned from "GetPrivateProfileString", but when I exclude and then include the Class file (which includes this code), the expected value is returned and it works fine till the time I close and open the solution again.

Any idea what wrong is going on here?

Comment: You need to stop using `GetPrivateProfileString`. It's not fit for purpose. Use an INI file parser. A websearch will reveal many such things.

Comment: Thanks David for replying, but still I have to figure this problem, my client wants the code to be put this way only.

Comment: I'm not interested in helping anyone call this function. You can read the documentation as well as I do and see the instruction not to call it. Good luck.

Comment: There are many other ini file parsers that don't come with the baggage of the GetPrivateProfileString

Comment: You have asked the same question on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/986527/GetPrivateProfileString-Strange-Behaviour-works-on) and I provided you the same answer. Additionally I offered you my library for replacement and a help if you need any to use it... I guess some people just don't accept help...

Comment: Hey Mario.. I posted on both the websites to get the maximum expert replies. It was because of suggestions from you guys that yesterday i have scheduled a meeting with my client today to discuss on this and omit using the primitive GetPrivateProfileString. I would respond to this post once I am done with the meeting. Please bear wid me for a while.. Again, thanks for replying to my post

Comment: Guys, thanks for responding to the post.... We came to conclusion, we will be reading an XML file instead of INI files, omitting the use of WinApi. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [David Heffernan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505088/david-heffernan), we agreed to stop using GetPrivateProfileString, instead we are using now XMLs to fix this up.

Though this technology is quite primitive and not recommended at all, but just to answer the question, I worked and found what the actual problem was.

The issue was with "m_sIniFileName".
The Software which was changing the IniFiles didn't have privelges to actually modify the C:\WINDOWS\Win.Ini (files from where we are reading the values) , instead the values were getting updated in Virtual Store,
C:\Users(User)\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Windows\win.ini.

Please refer to the  [link](http://www.interworks.com/blogs/dsmith/2011/09/21/disabling-windows-7-virtual-store) for more information.

So, users has to grant the permission to the third party software to modify C:\WINDOWS\Win.Ini (not recommended)

Once the full access is granted to the software, it worked.

This solution is highly NOT recommended, please use another methods to achieve the same functionality